# Excel form using Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have an spreadsheed with a column called "manufacture" and a list of manufactures below, so I'm trying to create a search form, to look for the manucture. I'm following this example: https://www.udemy.com/blog/excel-vba-vlookup/ but I think I'm having a problem when setting the spreadsheet where this column of data is. I'm doing this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Label1 = Globals.Sheet1.VLookup(ComboBox1, Range("D1:D210"), 2, False)
End Sub
```

but I'm getting an error which says 'Runtime error '424' object is required". In my case, I just put a combo, a command button and a label, and also a command button in the spreadsheet. So when I run it, I have a combo which shows all my manufactures, but when I select one and click on "find it", I have that error.

Thank you.

Natalia.

Comment: So set a breakpoint on the `Label1` line and run you app, and then when the breakpoint is triggered examine the objects on that line (`Globals`, `Sheet1`, `ComboBox1`, and `Range`) to see which one is `nothing`. What does that indicate?

Comment: Thank you. How can I see the values of Globals and Sheet1? Also, instead of writing the result in a new column, is it possible to select it, the same when doing CTRL+F? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change: `Globals.Sheet1.VLookup(ComboBox1, Range("D1:D210"), 2, False)`
To: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ComboBox1, Sheet1.Range("D1:D210"), 1, False)`

## Explanation:

1. You are using the VB.NET object model in VBA.
2. Your range for the vLookup has only 1 column, but you told it to look in the second of 1 columns.

Comment: thank you! that is working :) I have just another small question: the 1 before the False is to write the result in the first column? Is it possible to select the value instead of writing it in a new place? Thank you!!

Comment: The 1 before false is to tell which column to return.  For example, if you chose the range D1:F210, Excel would compare ComboBox1 to the values in Column D, but the number before false would tell which of the 3 selected columns to return (1 would return D, 2 would return E and 3 would return F.)